# Gstreamer and QWidgets

Tags: video, qt4, gstreamer, qt4.8, qtgstreamer

After reading this discussion: [Draw on top of xoverlay using Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761481/draw-on-top-of-xoverlay-using-qt) I've ended up with this code:

```
class Player : public QGst::Ui::VideoWidget { ... }

void Player::play() {
  QGst::PipelinePtr pipeline = QGst::ElementFactory::make("playbin2").dynamicCast<QGst::Pipeline>();
  watchPipeline(pipeline);
  pipeline->setProperty("uri", "/path/to/my/video.mp4");
  QGst::BusPtr bus = pipeline->bus();
  bus->addSignalWatch();
  QGlib::connect(bus, "message", this, &Player::onBusMessage);
  pipeline->setState(QGst::StatePlaying);
}
```

So I have my video playing in this `QWidget`. Now I want to add another `QWidget` on top of this one to draw something or to place another `QWidget` with alpha blending. I tried this code in the main app:

```
Player *player = new Player(this);
QWidget *videoOverlay = new QWidget(player);
// set the videoOverlay geometry
videoOverlay->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
videoOverlay->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

But I get a black opaque `QWidget`. There is no transparency at all.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
videoOverlay->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoBackground);
videoOverlay->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
videoOverlay->setAutoFillbackground(false);
```

Or this:

```
videoOverlay->setAutoFillBackground(true);
videoOverlay->setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen);
videoOverlay->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Window);
// make the widget transparent
QPalette transparent;
transparent.setColor(QPalette::Window, QColor(128,64,128)); // transparent color
videoOverlay->setPalette(transparent);
```

Third option:

```
videoOverlay->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
videoOverlay->setStyleSheet("background:transparent;");
```

More information about how to make widgets transparent:

- http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32310-Translucent-Qt-widget
- http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3239

Comment: This - like my code - works until I issue the watchPipeline(pipeline); on the target QWidget. After that the videoOverlay QWidget looses the transparency features.

Comment: @Mark Edited my answer. Also, can you set the attributes after issuing `watchPipeline(pipeline)`?

Comment: I'm very sorry but none of those works. If I set the parameter before the watchPipeline I have some transparency which will be lost just after the function. Setting them after issuing watchPipeline has no effect. Here the code of videoWidget.cpp (which contains that function) [link](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/qt-gstreamer/html/videowidget_8cpp_source.html)